# MapBox SDK Download Not Authorized from build.gradle

Tags: gradle, mapbox

I am trying to follow the instructions in the mapbox [installation guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/maps/guides/install/) but I am getting the error:

```
{"message":"Not Authorized - No Token"}
```

I am reasonably confident that I am using the correct password - and have even generated a new one to be sure. I have tried both the private password (as recommended) and my public one. I have also hard-coded the password into my *build.gradle* file, just in case I was failing to get it from the properties file. This is incredibly frustrating since, clearly, until I get the SDK, I can't write any code :-(

This is a really shame, since the V10 SDK looks much better than previous versions and has more sample code, which looks like being a huge help!

I am using Android Studio V4.2.2 running on MacOS Big Sur 11.5.

Comment: Which "_properties file_"?  You've copied https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency yeah? and added `MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN` to gradle.properties? Can you print it out in the build script to check it's there?

Comment: And you're using a token, not your password?

Comment: I put my password into the global gradle.properties file, as per normal. I have also printed it out, to confirm that the value is being located. Finally, as noted, I pasted the actual value into the build.gradle file - Just To Be Sure ;-) I'm not sure what token you are referring to - I'm just using the password generated via my mapbox account.

Comment: @tim_yates, I just might have been an idiot here, for which I can only apologise :-( The build error that I am getting is: Could not HEAD 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.21/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.21.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
**Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project** However, I'm pretty certain the I am not in offline mode - the only way of setting this seems to be from the gradle tool window.

Comment: ...The 'not authorised' error is what I get if I click on the URL in the error - which makes sense since I'm not passing any credentials that way

Comment: Sigh, I wrote a simple shell script that tried to download the pom file. First error I got was that I needed a token with DOWNLOADS:READ scope. I created a new token with this scope and then got the error File Not Found. Beginning to lose faith in MapBox :-( btw: MapBox refer interchangeably to token or password.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the best is it...  I assume they want you to pass the secret token in the second part of https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235187/discussion-between-andy-and-tim-yates).

Answer (score 1):

In conclusion, my original error was due to me not following the advice on the mapbox website, by configuring a token/password with **DOWNLOADS:READ** scope. My investigation was greatly helped by @tim_yates' input, which lead me to write a shell script that tested the remote connection, using a command of the form:

```
curl -u mapbox:<token> -G <url>
```

This returned much more meaningful errors than the ones returned by gradle inside Android Studio.

Sadly, this is not the end, since it has now left me with a new tranche of errors. However, at least it has moved me me forward a bit ;-/